# Why does the knife tool create random extra geometry?

Tags: modeling, mesh, knife-tool

The knife tool seems to be generating duplicate vertices, creating additional unwanted geometry. Is this a bug or related to camera or tool settings?

Any idea?

[image]

edit:
Clarifying the vert:
[image]

Comment: What extra geometry are you referring to? I don't see it in your illustration, just the geometry I would expect to see from using the knife tool.

Comment: @brasshat the last selected vertex on the giff is duplicated

Comment: @brasshat yes, the last selected vert I move around. I've added a still image to show the specific one.

Comment: One duplicated vertex and you call it a bug? When you use a knife tool how often does it happen? Frequently or in this case only?

Comment: @PaulGonet Not calling it a bug. Just asking if it is or something related to a setting someone might know. It happens randomly around half the time. I haven't been able to reproduce it consistently based on any setting or scenario,

Comment: That is just an expected limitation of detecting intersections with  mesh objects, some times it just fails to read depth or face intersections and an occasional extra vertex is created.

Comment: I can reproduce that same effect by extruding an edge, cancelling, and then using the knife tool.  Is it possible that the mesh has duplicate geometry?  Remove doubles maybe?  In other words, if the problem is repeatable enough for you to produce a gif, I would consider the mesh as being the culprit.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I have the same thoughts. FredLierman you may have accidentally pressed the LMB just before the knife snapped to the edge. That's all. Not a big deal here. BTW I wonder why this question have so many upvotes while some very valuable ones have less...

Comment: @PaulGonet "*I wonder why this question have so many upvotes*" Yeah, you got me wondering the same. I guess animated gifs are attractive, other than that it is pretty useless. Its like asking why there are bugs in software. Well obviously humans ain't perfect and mistakes are made.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for all the suggestions. However there are no doubles and I'm not clicking middle mouse button.

The reason for the upvotes is possibly that this is a common issue/question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using line tool instead, it is pretty similar to knife tool, works pretty well and has some additional functionality, like create faces and objects
https://github.com/Mano-Wii/Addon-Snap-Utilities-Line/wiki

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. When posting an answer where you link to an addon or external resource please try to provide a short description of the page you are linking to, why it is relevant and what it does.